# How to show/hide certain HTML blocks of a component based on the actual route in Angular 14?

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-router, angular14

Let's say I have two routes in Angular 14: *user* and *admin*. I also have a component called *some-content*.

*user.component.html*:

```
<app-some-content></app-some-content>
```

*admin.component.html* (same as *user.component.html*):

```
<app-some-content></app-some-content>
```

*some-content.component.ts*:

```
export class SomeContentComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _router: Router) { }
  router: Router = this._router;
```

*some-content.component.html*:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Last name</th>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th>Some stuff</th>
    <th>Some other stuff</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let person of persons">
      <td>{{person.lastName}}</td>
      <td>{{person.firstName}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="router.url === '/user'">{{person.someStuff}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="router.url === '/admin'" (click)="callSomeFunction()">{{person.someStuff}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="router.url === '/admin'">
        <!-- html stuff -->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, I used the *Router* service property *url* with **ngIf* to show/hide data based on the actual view. Just a few lines of code needed, but is it the proper way to do things?

Comment: You shouldn't link your state directely to your URL.

Comment: This works. But it’s probably better to handle this in the user component itself and use an input on the some-content component that tells it to render itself or not (or even use an *ngIf directly on the some-component. The idea to keep presentational component as dumb as possible.

Comment: Honestly I tried with `@Input` and calling methods from other controllers, but things went messy and it didn't work at all.

Comment: Is it better to have two very similar *component.html* files with some duplicated methods in the two *component.ts* files?